# A question about inflection point

Tags: calculus

Does the function
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2   & x\leq1\\
2-x^2 & x>1
\end{cases}
$$
has an inflection point at $x=1$, or it hasn't because $f$ isn't differentiable at $x=1$? Thanks!

Comment: This is really a case of definitions. How do you define an "inflection point." And there isn't one definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprise surprise! A function doesn't have to be differentiable in order to have an inflection point. Simply put, an inflection point is a point at which $f(x)$ switches concavity.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^-}f''(x)=2$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^+}f''(x)=-2$

We can easily see that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Because the concavity changes signs at $x=1$, yes, $f(x)$ has a point of inflection.

Comment: If it has to be differentiable, then no, it is not an inflection point. If it doesn't necessarily have to be differentiable, then yes, it is an inflection point. There are multiple definitions, though.

Comment: The common definitions require the curve to have a tangent.

Comment: That's why I said if it has to be differentiable then there is no inflection point at x=1 @YvesDaoust there are two definitions not sure which one to use. one isn't right and one isn't wrong. just convention

Answer (score 0):

In an inflection point need to exist a tangent line to the graph of the function, which in our case says that $f$ must be differentiable.

Thus, $(1,1)$ is not inflection point.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I can say only that Wikipedia is wrong and it's very big mistake.

Comment: No, it is not. Several other sites have a similar definition. There is no requirement of differentiability in some definitions. Definitions vary. One isn't "wrong" and the other "right."

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Definitions vary. FWIW [Wolfram's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html) agrees with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point).

Comment: @Thomas Andrews If we wish to work with essence of an inflection point, then it's better to take my (not only my) definition.

Comment: What the heck does that mean? That just means, "I want it to be the definition." The reason to choose the geometric definition is that it is geometric, so it captures the intuitive "essence" of the idea. Neither definition is "wrong" nor "better."

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: it is a very big mistake to believe that both Wikipedia and Wolfram are wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg `essence of an inflection point` Sorry, don't know what you are getting at with that. For example $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ looks very much like it has an inflection point at $x=0$ (and it does, indeed, by most accounts), though it's not differentiable there.

Comment: @dxiv For the given function it's enough to understand that $f$ is nod  differentiable for $x=1$. In your example the point $(0,0)$ is inflection point because in this point there is a tangent line to the graph. I fixed my post. See now, please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It is a matter of definition, and not all authors require that a tangent line must exist at an inflection point. Some consider that e.g. $\,|x^2-4|\,$ has inflection points at $\,x=\pm 2\,$. See for example Robert Israel's reply [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/4iJ142kvqHs/9swrx8EpUqkJ).

Comment: @dxiv I agree with you that it's a matter of definition. But, in my opinion, for the right thinking it's better the definition with a possibility  existence tangent  at the  inflection point.